# Manage UDP packets with IDAS fiware device manager

Tags: cloud, protocols, iot, fiware

I am trying to make my own LoRa server at fiware.
I have bought a Gateway(Lorank8v1) which catches LoRa RF packets and send their data to Cloud through UDP protocol.

I would like to ask which IOT agent should I use at Fiware in order to succeed it. There are 3 IOT agents which support different protocols(LWM2M/COAP transport, UL2.0/HTTP or MQTT transport, JSON/MQTT transport).

I am new in this field and i find the protocol compatibility a little bit complicated.

Comment: What programming language are you using? There are specific libraries to some of these protocols.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!I have already used lora-gateway-bridge to do this.However,is there something like this for COAP? Generally, i cannot understand from the fiware's docs the pros and cons of every protocol.Of course, i am going to move on this solution because i haven't anything else in my hands.All IOT agents ara services imlemented in node javascript.I am going to implement my app logic using PHP and specifically the curl library for the REST calls.I wish everything to go well.

Comment: It is just need some care related to the integration of the parts: learn how to use them separately and then learn how to integrate them. If you think the answer helped you, please mark it as "the answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [LoRa Gateway Bridge](https://docs.loraserver.io/lora-gateway-bridge/overview/):

> LoRa Gateway Bridge is a service which abstracts the packet-forwarder UDP protocol into JSON over MQTT. The package-forwarder software is running on most gateways and its purpose is to communicate with the LoRa chipset.

With this, you can use the MQTT IoT Agent. I think this is a good choice, because MQTT seems to be the most used between the three protocols.

Also, you can take a look at [FIWARE LoRa IoT Agent](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-openlpwa-iotagent):

> This project is a bridge between the Orange LoRa®* network and the OMA NGSIv1 protocol used by the Orion Context Broker as well as by other components of the FIWARE ecosystem.

I hope this can help you.